# Minor ambiguous wording in the Code section of the Markdown Editing Help

Tags: discussion, editor

> If you want to have a preformatted block within a list, indent by eight spaces:
>
> ```
> 1. This is normal text.
> 2. So is this, but now follows a code block:
>
>        Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
>        That's four spaces for the list
>        and four to trigger the code block.
> ```

My initial reading was "So is this, but [it] now follows a code block" (my brain understood a silent subject) rather than the intended "So is this, but a code block now follows [it]".

Suggested fix: "So is this, but it's now followed by a code block:" or "So is this, but now here's a code block:".

If I'm just lacking sleep (almost certainly true), feel free to nuke this.

Comment: And now my brain wants the indented text to form a haiku.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was meant as this:

1. Do this:

   ```
   code code code
   ```
2. Otherwise, don't:

   Oops, doesn't work!

Markdown:

```
1. Do this:

        code code code
2. Otherwise, don't:

    Oops, doesn't work!
```